# ExoPlayer2 set initial track in playlist

Tags: android, android-video-player, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm using ExoPlayer 2.3.1 for playing the list of videos. I'm using code from sample:

```
MediaSource mediaSource = mediaSources.length == 1 ? mediaSources[0]
                    : new ConcatenatingMediaSource(mediaSources);
player.prepare(mediaSource, !haveResumePosition, false);
```

It's working fine, but I want to select video to play first.
For example I have 3 videos, when I clicks on second it should play and prev/next buttons in player should be available. Now it starts playing from the first `mediaSource` in array, and I can't find a way to set index of initial track or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

Please check this out [seekTo(windowIndex, positionMs)](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Player.java#L261). It says

> Seeks to a position specified in milliseconds in the **specified window**.

Example:

```
player.seekTo(3, C.TIME_UNSET);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```